# Can i dump dll from pagefile?

Tags: memory, memory-dump

Like the title of this question, im trying to dump dll of process but it only return a message Error: Dllbase is paged (pic below)

[image]

So is the dll on pagefile and can i extract it from pagefile.sys ?
Thanks